# CSS: Make headings slightly larger if they have a certain class

Tags: html, css

Say that my base stylesheet defines that when I have something like:

```
<h2>My heading</h2>
...
<h3>My other heading</h3>
```

the first heading will use font-size: 1.5em and the other one 1.3 em. What I'm trying to achieve is that when those heading have classes like this:

```
<h2 class="larger">My heading</h2>
...
<h3 class="larger">My other heading</h3>
```

both headings should be 20% larger than what they would have been without the classes. Is it possible to somehow achieve this using a single CSS rule, i.e.:

```
.larger {
    /* what to put in here? */
}
```

or will I need to create rules for `h1.larger`, `h2.larger`, `h3.larger` etc. separately and duplicate the styling rules?

Answer (score 3):

I dont believe this can be done in a single rule, at the simplest level, you could surely use:

```
h2.larger{
  font-size:1.8em;
}

h3.larger{
  font-size:1.56em;
}
```

Where the font size is 1.2x the original in both cases- although this is hard coded.

Comment: yes, that was. `element.class` will work if you use `font-size` with bigger number, and actually that's normal.

Comment: You can also use `element#id` if you need to specify __ONLY ONE__ element.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way…

But you could add a children to each `h` and it will make what you want:
(explanation at the bottom)

**HTML:**

```
<h2>My heading</h2>
<h3>My other heading</h3>
<br>
<br>
<h2 class="larger">My heading</h2>
<h3 class="larger">My other heading</h3>
<br>
<br>
<h2><span class="larger">My heading</span></h2>
<h3><span class="larger">My other heading</span></h3>
```

**CSS:**

```
h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.larger {
    font-size: 130%;
}
```

Case 1: the size is applied as normal to the `h`'s

Case 2: the size is applied to both `h`'s disregarding their `font-size` initial definition.

Case 3: adding a child (in this case a `span`) will obbey the `font-size` of the parent as intended

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z3ztr/

Comment: This answer as well as @SW4's answer are probably correct. Can you please somehow merge that other answer before I accept it?